# TeamCity agent error "failed to perform checkout on agent"

Tags: github, teamcity, agent, teamcity-7.0

I am running my TeamCity 7 server and agent on MacOS. My repo is on github. I use ssh and I know that the authentication is correctly configured, because the test is successful.

The build works fine when I use VCS Checkout Mode "Automatically on server", however when I use VCS Checkout mode "Automatically on agent" I get this error.

```
[13:40:35][Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: '/usr/bin/git fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master' command failed.
stderr: java.io.IOException: Authentication failed
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.authenticate(SSHMain.java:275)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:159)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:139)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have correct ssh key on th agent? "Test connection" in VCS root settings tests connection only between TeamCity server and your repository.

Comment: I guess I don't, but how do I figure out the account of the agent? Can I change the account under which the agent works?

Comment: Account of the agent is the account under which the agent was started. So yes you can change that.

Answer (score 30):

Try adding teamcity.git.use.native.ssh=true as a config parameter into your build configuration.

It is what helped me solve a similar problem. I learned this trick from [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24955).

Comment: This hint fixed it for me as well.

Comment: This made my day! Thank you so-so much!

Comment: This [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-52052#comment=27-2607007) might also be useful if you have Putty SSH keys (see comment thread)

Comment: This fixed it for me even though my build log said nothing at all about authentication failure!

Answer (score 2):

What was not at all obvious to me is that the Default Private Key *on the server* is copied to the agent and used there. I tried first in vain to add the private key to the user the agent was running as (obviously on the agent machine). But then I added the private key to the user that was running TeamCity on the server machine, and then the Agent Side checkout started working.

I also used the `teamcity.git.use.native.ssh=true` property, but I don't think it helped with this particular problem.

The only trace of this information was in [this comment](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5305545?tstart=0).