# TeamCity agent error “failed to perform checkout on agent. exit code: 128”

Tags: git, teamcity

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841059/teamcity-agent-error-failed-to-perform-checkout-on-agent)  link do not help me.

> VCS parameters: Fetch URL: http://***.com:7990/scm/clear/pro.git
>   Default branch: refs/heads/master Branch specification:+:refs/heads/*
>   Authentication method: Password
>
> Connection test complete successfully

[image: example]

I see files in repository

checkout rules:

```
+:. => pro
```

Build log

```
[15:56:00] :     [Updating sources] VCS Root: pro (1s)
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] checkout rules: =>pro; revision: 10e1d06cce989c706b1ca0bfce6376cf47416bb8
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] Git version: 2.8.2.0
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe show-ref
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe show-ref refs/heads/master
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe show-ref refs/heads/master
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper211792100691636860.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8519024404529146114.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[15:56:00] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper211792100691636860.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8519024404529146114.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper211792100691636860.bat store: C:BuildAgenttempbuildTmpcredHelper211792100691636860.bat: command not found
[15:56:00] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper211792100691636860.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8519024404529146114.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] fatal: remote error: Repository does not exist
[15:56:00] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper211792100691636860.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8519024404529146114.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
[15:56:00] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper211792100691636860.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8519024404529146114.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] access it.
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe init --bare
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe remote add origin http://user@vm-cint03.unix.com:7990/scm/clear/pro.git
[15:56:00] :         [VCS Root: pro] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass7759894979385805778.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[15:56:01] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass7759894979385805778.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat store: C:BuildAgenttempbuildTmpcredHelper2255037882340038481.bat: command not found
[15:56:01] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass7759894979385805778.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] fatal: remote error: Repository does not exist
[15:56:01] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass7759894979385805778.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
[15:56:01] :             [[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git]: git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass7759894979385805778.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] access it.
[15:56:01]E:     [Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: 'git.exe -c credential.helper=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass7759894979385805778.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master' command failed.
exit code: 128
stderr: C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\credHelper2255037882340038481.bat store: C:BuildAgenttempbuildTmpcredHelper2255037882340038481.bat: command not found
fatal: remote error: Repository does not exist
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
access it.
```

I have a permission and I can clone it.

What could be the cause and how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

Removing `C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-2EAC5546.git` helped me.

Comment: It's work for me but after that, I got another error but I tried to run build agent again and again on three attempt its work for me ... hahaha don't know how

Answer (score 2):

Removing folders located at C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\system\git\git-XXXX.git on the TeamCity server worked. I deleted the folders corresponding to the time when the issue first occurred and after. Because I didn't want to screw anything up, I backed up all of the folders to be removed first, but there were no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder from C:\BuildAgent\system\git*.git folder which resolved your problem

Answer (score -1):

In my case (teamcity 2020), I had to replace

```
url = git@github.com:'Projectname'.git
```

with

```
url = https://github.com/'Projectname'.git
```

in the git config file of the agents.

Not sure why, however, it solved the issue...